# Historic per minute or hour price with googlefinance in googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Looking at the documentation it does not seem so but I would want to know if there are hacks or other tools perhaps that make it possible to use the google sheet formula:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC","close","07/07/2017")
```

with a hour or minute value of any kind, for isntance:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC","price","07/07/2017 12:00")
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, this is not possible in google sheets

you can get only daily or weekly value as per documentation:

[image]

for an hour or minute window, you will need to find a non-javascript website that hosts such data and scrape it from there with some IMPORT formula